# Finding mystery Linux memory usage - not caches or slab (or ballooning?)

Tags: linux, memory, xen

I have a Xen VM running Debian Linux with a weirdly large amount of RAM used.  What might be the culprit?  I believe I've ruled out the usual suspects of disk caching, kernel slab usage, and memory ballooning.

`free -h` shows:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8Gi       3.6Gi        87Mi       0.0Ki        55Mi        33Mi
Swap:          1.0Gi       275Mi       748Mi
```

So almost all of the VM's 3.8 GiB of RAM is used, and only a tiny fraction of that usage is from the kernel's disk cache.

`smem -kt` doesn't attribute the memory to any process:

```
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
   ⋮
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   52 1                                      214.4M   128.4M   133.2M   146.6M
```

`smem -w -kt` says the memory belongs to the kernel:

```
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory          3.6G -20205568.0       3.6G 
userspace memory             133.6M      77.6M      56.0M 
free memory                   87.8M      87.8M          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                               3.8G     146.1M       3.6G
```

(Also, that negative number seems weird.)

`/proc/meminfo` says, among other things, that the kernel slab allocator is only responsible for about 95 MiB of the RAM usage (and also doesn't really give an indication about what *is* using the RAM):

```
MemTotal:        3973392 kB
MemFree:           89144 kB
MemAvailable:      41860 kB
Buffers:            5084 kB
Cached:            37972 kB
SwapCached:        30000 kB
Active:            52356 kB
Inactive:          77832 kB
Active(anon):      30756 kB
Inactive(anon):    56396 kB
Active(file):      21600 kB
Inactive(file):    21436 kB
Unevictable:          80 kB
Mlocked:              80 kB
SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
SwapFree:         775576 kB
Dirty:               104 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         78660 kB
Mapped:            91004 kB
Shmem:                20 kB
KReclaimable:      28348 kB
Slab:              96740 kB
SReclaimable:      28348 kB
SUnreclaim:        68392 kB
KernelStack:        4288 kB
PageTables:         6768 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3035268 kB
Committed_AS:    1697316 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       10028 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             2352 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      428032 kB
DirectMap2M:     3799040 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

If I understand the Xen memory stuff correctly, the system hasn't lost much RAM to memory ballooning.  `/sys/devices/system/xen_memory/xen_memory0/info/current_kb` contains `4079228`, which matches the system's reported RAM well enough.  In the same directory, `high_kb` and `low_kb` contain `0` and `16384`, respectively.  I believe that means the Xen balloon driver has only claimed 16 MiB of RAM.

What am I missing?  What else could be using so much of the system's memory?